# How to dismiss UIAlertController without calling viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, swift

I"m calling a `UIAlertController` using `presentViewController` from my main vc. Problem is is that when I `dismissViewController` it reloads the entire main vc by calling `viewDidLoad`. I use unwinds in many of my other vc's but I don't know how to do it on a `UIAlertController` or if it's the proper way to get rid of an alert. How do I properly dismiss the alert without triggering a reload?

Comment: viewDidLoad should not be called again going back to the mainVC where the alert was presented from some thing else is off. is there anything calling viewDidLoad manually?

Comment: Alright, I feel kind of dumb on this one. I never just tried clicking an alert button before wiring up a function to dismiss the alert. Apparently dismissal is built in with any button press on a UIActionController. I'm not sure what method it's calling but it's not causing causing the presenting viewController to be reloaded.